error when adding audio plugins and shared_preferences Error: Type 'Uint8' not found
I'm getting this error in some applications I'm making and I noticed that this problem occurs whenever I add plugins like: shared_preferences, path_provider and plugins related to audios. If you can help I would be very grateful
the error menssage:
enter image description here
my pubspec:
page_transition: ^2.1.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.4.0
  firebase_core: ^2.29.0
  google_mobile_ads: ^5.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.19.1
  flame: ^1.8.2
  flame_tiled: ^1.11.0
  awesome_dialog: ^3.2.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.3

I already tried updating flutter and even changing the path_provider version, but it didn't work
